# How to script cursor movements in vim?

Tags: macos, vim

I'd like to set up a mapping to make it easy for me to send lines to the system clipboard in vim.

I'd normally specify a range, and write that range to `pbcopy` (I'm on OSX, where `pbcopy` "pastes to the pasteboard"), like this:

```
:20,23w !pbcopy
```

To make this more convenient, I'd like to set up a mapping to fill in the bulk of this command, but then return to the start of the line to allow me to fill in the range I want.

Essentially this:

```
nnoremap <leader>g :w !pbcopy
```

but that leaves the cursor at the end of the line. Is there any way I can create a mapping that adds the text and leaves the cursor at the start of the line for range insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to go to the begining of the so that you can enter a distance you could try the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>g :w !pbcopy<c-b>
```

`<c-b>` will bring the cursor to the beginning of the line in order for you to enter a distance.

alternatively you could select your text visually and have the following mapping in order to copy your selection and restore your cursor to where it was in the beginning:

```
vnoremap <leader>g :w !pbcopy<cr>`[
```

`` `[ `` could be replaced with `gv` to re-select the lines

Comment: Visually selecting and then copying the selection will work nicely, thanks. I don't follow exactly what happens with the variation where you set and return to a mark. How are you specifying which region to copy in this case?

Comment: my apologies. I misread the question. i have fixed it with a proper solution to your original question

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot for providing the additional information after I'd accepted your answer! Yes, that makes much more sense to me now.